# Rails app errors on view within Google App Engine Flex with Command "webpack" not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a Rails application to Google App Engine Flex.

`app.json`:

```
runtime: ruby
env: flex
entrypoint: bundle exec rails server -p 8080
```

`Gemfile`:

```
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.11'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.3'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.6'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.2'
gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
gem "appengine", "~> 0.6.0"
```

deploy output:

```
...
Step #1: Step 15/18 : RUN access_cloud_sql --lenient && bundle exec rake assets:precompile || true
Step #1:  ---> Running in 725718ed7002
Step #1: Started cloud_sql_proxy.
Step #1: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Step #1: I, [2022-03-30T22:17:20.368483 #52]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
Step #1: I, [2022-03-30T22:17:20.369454 #52]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
Step #1: I, [2022-03-30T22:17:20.370448 #52]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/trix-6fd35bb8fae1d6a795115763ca265369b9750f73a1c6283a0b0ef4b6c2d550c8.css
Step #1: I, [2022-03-30T22:17:20.371103 #52]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/trix-6fd35bb8fae1d6a795115763ca265369b9750f73a1c6283a0b0ef4b6c2d550c8.css.gz
Step #1: Compiling...
Step #1: Compilation failed:
Step #1: yarn run v1.22.18
Step #1: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Step #1:
Step #1:
Step #1: error Command "webpack" not found.
Step #1:
...
```

When deployed viewing the site has the following errors in the Logs Explorer:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application.js in /app/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
):
     7:     <%= csp_meta_tag %>
     8: 
     9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    10:     <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    11:     <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    12:   </head>
    13: 
  
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:10
```

Comment: Have you tried running the command `rails webpacker:compile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to my app.yaml fixed it for me:

```
runtime_config:
  build:
    - yarn install && bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```

From [your github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docker/issues/216) (thanks! ;)